# How Bag of Features works?

Tags: c++, algorithm, computer-vision, k-means

I'm not sure that this is the right forum for this question, I'm sorry otherwise.

I'm quite new to the [Bag of Features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision) model and I'm trying to implement in order to represent an image through a vector (for a CBIR project).

From what I've understood, given a training set `S` of `n` images and supposing that we want to represent an image through a vector of size `k`, these are the steps for implementing BoF:

1. For each image `i`, compute the set of keypoints and from that compute the set of descriptor `i-D`.
2. Put all together the set of descriptor from all the images, so now we have `D`.
3. Run the `k` means (where `k` is defined above) algorithm on `D`, so now we have `k` clusters and each descriptor vector belongs exactly to one cluster.
4. Define `iv` as the resulting BoF vector (of size `k`) relative to image `i`. Each dimension is initialized to 0.
5. For each image `i`, and for each descriptor `d` belonging to `i-D`, find out which cluster `d` belongs between all the `k` clusters. Supposing that `d` belongs to the `j`-th cluster, then `vi[j]++`.

What is not clear to me is how to implement point 5., so how do we understand to which cluster a descriptor belongs to, **in particular if the image that we are trying to compute the BoF vector is a query image (and so didn't belong to the initial dataset)**? Should we find the nearest neighbor (1-NN) in order to understand to which cluster the query descriptor belongs to?

**WHY I NEED THIS - THE APPLICATION:**

I'm implementing the BoF model in order to implement a CBIR: given a query image `q`, find the most similar image `i` of `q` in a dataset of images. In order to do this, we need to solve the 1-approximate nearest neighbor problem, for example using [LSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing). The problem is that the input in LSH each image is represented as a vector, so we need the BoF in order to do that! I hope that now it's clearer why I need it :)

Please, let me know also if I did some mistake in the procedure described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your algorithm is doing is generating the equivalent of words for a image. The set of "words" is not meant to be a final result, but just something that makes it simple to use with other machine learning techniques.

In this setup, you generate a set of k clusters from the initial feature (the keypoints from point 1).
Then you describe each image by the number of keypoints that fall in each cluster (just like you have a text composed of words from a dictionary of length k).

Point 3 says that you take all the keypoints from the traing set images, and run [k-means algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering), to figure out some reasonable separation between the points. This basically establishes what the words are.

So for a new image you need to compute the keypoints like you did for the training set and then using the clusters you have already computed in training you figure out the feature vector for your new image. That is you convert your image into words from the dictionary you've built.

This is all a way to generate a reasonable feature vector from images (a partial result if you want). This is not a complete machine learning algorithm. To complete it you need to know what you want to do. If you just want to find the most similar image(s), then yes a nearest neighbor search should do that. If you want to label images, then you need to train a classifier (like naive-bayes) from the feature vector and use it to figure out the label for the query.

Comment: I'm so so so sorry, I'm stupid! It was not point 3. (which is simply k-means), but point 5. (where we define the resulting vector by associating each descriptor to a cluster and defining the histogram).

Comment: So, still, what it's not clear to me is "given an image query, how do we obtain the resulting BoF vector"? We have to find, for each descriptor, the 1-NN descriptor in the dataset and associate it to the relative cluster? Tell me if I'm not clear

Comment: Yes, to assign a descriptor you can get the closest neighbor. You can compute the radius of each cluster based on your training data and only assign it if the query point comes within that radius (in case you start getting queries that are very different from the training data).

Comment: Wow, that was smart, didn't think about the radius trick! Thanks!

Comment: Could you please give a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37698202/bag-of-words-featrues-locality-sensity-hashing-for-content-based-image-retriev) question?